# clean up the system in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10

i am using Ubuntu I want to clean up the log files in my system that are stored in /var/log every 3 month automatically how can I write a script to do so

Thank you

Comment: Manually? Try out a utility http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes i want to write a bash shell to do that

Answer (score 4):

The standard `logrotate(8)` utility is probably your best starting point.

The configuration file `/etc/logrotate.conf` defines some defaults, include daily, weekly, monthly rotation, the number of rotations to keep, permissions to use when creating new log files (`wtmp` and `btmp` on my system; perhaps also `utmp` on other systems). It can also define a directory to read configuration files -- which makes it far easier for distributions to package rotation files with the packages.

You can probably do what you want simply by changing `rotate 4` to `rotate 2` to cut the number of files in half. Edit the files in `/etc/logrotate.d/` if any of them specify their own `rotate` limits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write a bash script yourself to do that. All Linux environments come with with a tool called Cron that allows you to do schedule commands, scripts, etc.

It is well explained here on this page http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Removing all log files every 3 months would for example could be done by opening the Cron file of the user with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then adding the line

```
* * * 1,4,7,10 * rm /var/log/*.{1,2,3,4}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Deleting all logs rather than just old logs is a bit draconian.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Your answer is probably better, though. If there is a dedicated tool for managing logs it should be used.

Comment: This didnt work it gave me an error saying Authentication failure and when I wrote ayoya@ubuntu:~$ crontab -e
no crontab for ayoya why is this?

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam see the changes I made to the command. It should work now. However, you should consider using sarnold's solution which is probably safer.